# Photoshop Mockup Smart Layer is applying to all layers. How to apply this to only one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

Any help is appreciated. Thanks
[image]
https://mockups-design.com/free-box-in-grid-layout-mockup/

The green design on the left of each box is being duplicated to every layer selected for that side of each box mockup. There is multiple boxes and [their] sides to edit, but it's applying to all, when I want a different design on each.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Most mockups work by using smart objects.  If you don't want to use them all, you can just hide those you don't want by clicking the eye icon next to them in the layers panel.

Comment: You *really* need to be more descriptive and explain *exactly* what you want to do and where that's failing.  **Guessing**.... if you are trying to make each box *different*, chances are they all rely on the same smart objects -- which means you may need to do some *deconstruction* of the mock up prior to changing the smart object.

Comment: Sorry, The green design on the left of each box is being duplicated to every layer selected for that side of each box mockup. There is multiple boxes and theyre sides to edit but its applying to all, when I want a different design on each.

Answer (score 1):

The way smart objects work is you have 1 smart object which gets propagated many times. Essentially "clones" are created of the original Smart Object. When you edit the original or *any* clone... **all** clones will update to show edits.

To make each box *different* you'll need to **deconstruct** the mockup and create additional, independent, smart object layers for each box. Basically, you'll need to deconstruct the "link" a smart object has with all its "clones"

You can do this via the Layer's Panel menu - highlight a Smart Object layer and choose `New Smart Object via Copy`. You'll then need to reposition this *new* SO layer properly and remove the existing SO layer for *that* particular box... and then repeat for all other boxes which are to be different.

There's no "break link to original smart object" command that I'm aware of. Only the `New Smart Object via Copy` will duplicate, then break the link to the original smart object.

There's no easy, simple, one or two step process for this.

The point of that mock up is that all the boxes are the *same*. So, it would appear to be constructed to facilitate that aspect as one would expect.

---

The other option would be to rasterize the smart object layers converting them to standard, unlinked, raster layers you could then edit independently of each other. But with that, you'd need to transform each of these raster layers to match the perspective of each box again.